# Embed video in HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

I have an IP CAM which provides access to the audio/video using RTSP protocol. I can see the video using VLC player but I would like to be able to embed this video in a HTML5 page.

I know most browsers cant handle RTSP with HTML5. So I was wondering: is there any PHP code that I can use to parse RTSP video and output a compatible Chrome video format that I can play using `<video>` tag? Is there someway PHP output some stream of data so I can send it to the browser parse it into HTML5 video container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ffmpeg` to trascode from RTSP and HLS and then display that in a browser which supports it:

Something like this will give you a starting point, though you may need to tune it. If you're going off your own local network though you may need to use a 3rd party streaming solution like `Azure Media Services` or `Wowza`

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp:<stream> -fflags flush_packets -max_delay 1 -an -flags -global_header -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 3 -hls_wrap 3 -vcodec copy -y <file>.m3u8
```

Comment: that works but I would like to play it/stream it remotely, do you know how to do that @Offbeatmammal? I know some people tried it with ffserver but I couldnt make it work :(

Comment: ffserver has been deprecated so you'd either need to host the m3u8 and assets on a webserver and make that visible, or use a commercial streaming service such as Azure Media Services or Wowza